# AlarmManager set weekly alarm on a specified weekday time repeats on app open

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I want to repeat a notification in android at a scheduled time in a specific day of the week (8:30am Saturday). I have set up the code and the alarm works (with the notification). The alarm need not wake up the device and fires the notification on next wake up.

Problem: The alarm is fired once every time the app is newly opened.

Tried different combinations but cant get it to work. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

**MainActivity.java (OnCreate)**

```
AndroidHelper ahelper= new AndroidHelper();

public static long rand_news_notify_freq= AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7;
Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
ca.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);
ca.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
ca.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
ca.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
ca.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
ahelper.setAlarms(alarmMgr, getApplicationContext(), RandomNewsNotification.class, ca, rand_news_notify_freq);
```

**AndroidHelper.class**

```
public class AndroidHelper{
    public AndroidHelper()
    {

    }

    public void setAlarms(AlarmManager alarmMgr, Context tctx, Class alarmClass, Calendar calendar, long freq)
    {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(tctx, alarmClass);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(tctx, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        //alarmMgr.setRepeating(alarmMgr.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), freq, pendingIntent); // This is not working
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(alarmMgr.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), freq, pendingIntent); // This is not working too (same problem)
    }
}
```

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you want to set exact repeating or inexact repeating. for exact repeating, you yourself should handle repeating with exact methods and don't use repeating methods of alaramManager like setInexactRepeating.
also consider if device is on Doze mode, alaram won't fire. so you should use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle method to guarantee that the alarms will execute.

you can see more detail on Android Developer document:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms